# normal subgroup and its element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of $D_n$. Show that if $N$ contains a reflection, then$ N $contains $R^2$ and either $r$ or $rR$.

I'm not sure I understand which reflection $N$ contian, because $D_n$ has many reflection, and hot this can be use to show that $N $contains $R^2$ and either $r$ or $rR$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $N$ contains a reflection, say $rR^k$ for some $0\le k<n$. (Here, I suppose that $R$ is the basic rotation and $r$ the basic reflection.) Since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $D_n$, then for any $m\in D_n$, we have $mNm^{-1}\subseteq N$, so in particular, $m(rR^k)m^{-1}\in N$. Your job, here, is to find some $m\in D_n$ such that $m(rR^k)m^{-1}=r$ or $m(rR^k)m^{-1}=rR$. (Hint: $R^jrR^kR^{-j}=rR^{k-2j}$.) Once you've done that, use the closure of $N$ to show that $R^2\in N$. Your given reflection, and the one you've just proved to be in $N$, should be enough to get the job done.